# Wordpress themes not working properly - no images or css

Tags: css, wordpress, image

I have a strange problem with Wordpress. I needed to move the site to another domain and had issues setting everything up again. It works now, but for some reason the themes are not loading images or their CSS.

I thouhgt there is an error with the source links to the images/css, but nope. Installed fresh Wordpress on the server, even on my localhost with XAMPP, but same issue there. Currently only 1 theme is working properly. All the others, when I install them, or click on live demo when installing them from the admin panel in WP, they show only the text. No images, no CSS (at least for the text colors etc..) is being shown. Do you know what could be the reason for that? Even on a freshly installed WP it should work, right?

Thanks!

Comment: is your new server set up to serve css mime type?  in the network tab, does the css file get downloaded, if so does, is the type stylesheet?

Comment: Yup, its getting loaded and the type of the style.css file is stylesheet.

Comment: Actually, tried to install new theme. Chose Sydney and it did not load a single image or the CSS file. From the source code of the page, when I find the .css files and click on the link, it opens them. The path must be correct in this case, but why arent they loading?

Screenshot: http://store.picbg.net/pubpic/77/BF/7b5a69cc203c77bf.png

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried clearing your server cache and browser cache?

Comment: Browser cache yes, server cache I dont know how? But I am using a free hosting from freehostia and then setup the WP on my computer. Even the stock themes are not showing any images, but the path to the exact img files is correct.

Comment: If you are using free hosting you probably wont be able to clear server cache. And why did someone downvote me? I had this very problem yesterday and that was the fix?

Comment: (Wasn't me but) Probably because this looks like more of a comment than an answer - you shouldn't answer a question with another question

Comment: Not from me also. But for me at least he gives an answer in his question.